# Issue with simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am trying to use an API . In this regard I am facing an issue with simplexml_load_string(). My Code is as like below

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->_apikey . ":" . $this->_password);        
    $additionalHeaders ='';
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml', $additionalHeaders));
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $xml = simplexml_load_string($output);
```

My Error is as like below

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
```

Could anyone help me in this regard?? Thanks

Comment: Debug the contents of the $output variable. The error message says that it isn't valid XML.

Comment: @ThW: I love this. How does one _debug_ a string variable?

Comment: You do not do any error detection / handling whatsoever. What do you expect happens if an error occurs? How do you want to realize you got an error instead of the xml you are looking for?